# Connecting issue for Microsoft Database rows with Visual basic project

Tags: vb.net

We are connecting Microsoft database with visual basic and here is the code below for our login. It is a bank account system where the login details are account no. and pin. These details are from our database. Each user has a balance included in their details but when we click the balance button when we login the last balance from the last appears every time.

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class frmLogin
    Dim objConnection As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(
    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=ATMDB.accdb")

    Dim objCustomerDA As _
    New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from Account", objConnection)
    Dim objCustomerCB As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(objCustomerDA)
    Dim CustomerDS As New DataSet()
    Public AccountNumber, PIN As String
    Dim CustomerFound As Boolean
    Public CustomerNO As String

    Private Sub frmLogin_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Retrieve()
     End Sub


    Private Sub btnLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
        AccountNumber = Account_NumberTextBox.Text
        PIN = PINTextBox.Text


        For i As Integer = 1 To (CustomerDS.Tables("Account").Rows.Count)
            If CStr(CustomerDS.Tables("Account").Rows(i - 1).Item("Account_Number")) = AccountNumber And
                            CStr(CustomerDS.Tables("Account").Rows(i - 1).Item("PIN")) = PIN Then
                CustomerFound = True
                CustomerNO = CStr(CustomerDS.Tables("Account").Rows(i -1).Item("Account_Number"))
                Me.Hide()
                MessageBox.Show("Welcome to the system!")
                'AnotherPageName.Show()
                frmServices.Show()
                Exit For
            End If

            Account_NumberTextBox.Text = String.Empty
            PINTextBox.Text = String.Empty
        Next
        If CustomerFound = False Then
            MessageBox.Show("User ID or Password Incorrect", "Error",
           MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel)
        End If
    End Sub


    Private Sub Retrieve()
        CustomerDS.Clear()
        objCustomerDA.FillSchema(CustomerDS, SchemaType.Source, "Account")
        objCustomerDA.Fill(CustomerDS, "Account")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Above is the code for the login and below is the code for the balance button on the next form.

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class frmServices
    Dim objConnection As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(
        "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=ATMDB.accdb")

    Dim objCustomerDA As _
        New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from Account", objConnection)

    Dim objCustomerCB As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(objCustomerDA)

    Dim CustomerDS As New DataSet()
    Dim myAtm As New ATM
    Public AccountNumber, _Balance As String
    Dim i As Integer

    Private Sub frmLogin_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Retrieve()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Retrieve()
        CustomerDS.Clear()
        objCustomerDA.FillSchema(CustomerDS, SchemaType.Source, "Account")
        objCustomerDA.Fill(CustomerDS, "Account")


    End Sub
    Private Sub btnLodge_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLodge.Click
        frmDeposit.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnWithdraw_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
        btnWithdraw.Click
        frmWithdraw.Show()
        Me.Hide()

    End Sub


    Private Sub btnBalance_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBalance.Click

        frmBalance.BalanceTextBox.Text = _Balance
        frmLogin.Account_NumberTextBox.Text = AccountNumber
        For i As Integer = 1 To (CustomerDS.Tables("Account").Rows.Count)
            If CStr(CustomerDS.Tables("Account").Rows(i - 1).Item("Account_Number")) = AccountNumber Then
                CustomerDS.Tables("Account").Rows(i - 1).Item("Balance") = _Balance
            End If

            frmBalance.Show(CustomerDS.Tables("Account").Rows(i - 1).Item("Balance") = _Balance)
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Where do you set the variable _Balance_? In the code above you read it but there is no code that sets it.

Comment: You need to debug your code and explain EXACTLY how and where the behaviour of the code differs from your expectations. If you don;t know how to debug, now is the time to learn.

Comment: Thanks for responding its much appreciated.No we do not have our balance set. Should the balance be set in the login code or the second form where the balance button is located?